# Add queryset as_manager to the AbstractUser model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple model User that simply extends the AbstractUser class with some extra fields. I tried adding "objects = UserQuerySet.as_manager() but is giving me an error "get_by_natural_key() is not defined" when i try to create a superuser. It seems that it is overwriting the regular user manager so i am losing the methods that it comes with. I tried renaming the objects field to something else so I wouldnt be overwriting the default one but it still the same error. Is there any way to simply add querysets without creating whole new manager class, extending the BaseUserManager, adding all of the default methods from scratch, and adding my custom queryset to it? I just want to keep the regular UserManager and just add querysets.

```
class UserQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def more_ten(self):
        return self.filter(points__gt=10)

class User(AbstractUser):
    points = IntegerField(default=0)
    tester = UserQuerySet.as_manager()
    #objects = UserQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Comment: Can you share your custom user model and your custom queryset code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model), your custom user manager should inherit from [`BaseUserManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager)

```
class UserQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def more_ten(self):
        return self.filter(points__gt=10)


from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager as OldUserManager


class UserManager(OldUserManager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserQuerySet(model=self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints)


class User(AbstractUser):

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: I know. The question is if there is anyway to just use queryset_as_manager() isntead of having to explicitly create the manager or there is no way to do this. I tried having the queryset class inherit from BaseUserManager but that doesnt work.

Comment: @eliezerperlowitz the issue is that the methods that the `BaseUserManager` adds are not `QuerySet` methods so it is not possible to have a queryset that can return a  manager with those methods

Comment: Ik. Was trying to see if a shortcut was implemented ;(. Anyway tried your code but it says "AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'". You have any idea why it is not inheriting the createsuperuser method from BaseUserManager?

Comment: You may be able to get away with inheriting from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager as the only additional field you have added has a default

Comment: Thanks man. Just annoying that they dont have a shortcut to just use the default manager and use queryset.as_manager. Now gonna have write methods for queryset and managers. But appreciate the help.